# Clear stack before invoking another keyup - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a piece of code to take the value of an input field every time the value changes, delayed by 500ms(to check if the user is still adding more values), then use the value to fetch data from an API. The code works, when done inputting the values it fetches the data, but after the specified delayed time, it fetches again using a previous value.

Assuming I want to type 1-10 into the input field, but while at 8, I waited for a little time before continuing to 9, and when I get to 10, it fetches the data after the specified delayed time. After some time, it reverts back to when I waited at 8 and fetches the value at that point.

My code:

```js
function delay(fn, ms) {
    var timer = 0
    return function(...args) {
        clearTimeout(timer)
        timer = setTimeout(fn.bind(this, ...args), ms || 0)
    }
}


$("#acctNumber").on("keyup", delay(function(){
    url = '...'
    const fetchBankDetails = fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        return data
    });

    const detailFetchRes = async () => {
        const data = await fetchBankDetails;
        console.log(data)
    }
    detailFetchRes();
}, 500))
```

The requests that hits my server when I try `1445665997`:

```sh
web_1        | [18/Jul/2021 21:25:21] "GET /api/fetch/account/1445665997/044 HTTP/1.1" 200 137
web_1        | [18/Jul/2021 21:25:31] "GET /api/fetch/account/1445665/044 HTTP/1.1" 200 108
```

Comment: You don't seem to cancel or otherwise deal with no-longer-needed fetches.

Comment: Can you explain @Ouroborus? I don't get it

Comment: I replaced the fetch with a delayed promise resolve [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5y0xh1L/) and it seems to work as expected